# JS проверка существования файла на ПК из браузера типа Chrome

Tags: javascript, файловая-система, браузер, chromium, webapi

Есть строка с путём до файла "D:/Device/App/out/CPU.hex" как проверить что файл существует в программе на JS в браузере? под Windows и Linux.
Штудирование https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API
ни к чему не привели, топчусь на месте, какие есть способы?

Предыстория:
Пишу приложение для прошивки неких девайсов из под браузера Chrome. C COM-портом разобрался, обмен данными с девайсами наладил под любой ОС где работает Chromium. Теперь надо заливать в них что-то осмысленное. У меня уже есть аналогичная рабочая консольная программа на Node.JS но она неудобна пользователям так как надо ставить Node.JS и при nmp install компилируются ОС-зависимые модули что не у всех получается. Поэтому решил переписать аналогичный функционал на JS для браузера Chrome чтобы получит кроссплатформенность как сейчас на Node.
В программу на Node, передаётся json-файл с инфой для прошивки, где указаны абсолютные пути к файлам и настройкам прошивок лежащих на ПК пользователя, проверить наличие файлов по указанным путям на Node.JS и потом их прочитать не составляет труда (ибо есть прямое сообщение с файловой системой ОС), но как такое сделать в браузере?

Comment: У сайта никогда не будет доступа к файловой системе, потому что это не безопасно.

Comment: к счастью или сожалению, никак